# Show that if f is entire and $|f(z)|=1$ for all real numbers, then $f$ has no zeroes.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if f is entire and $|f(z)|=1$ for all real numbers, then $f$ has no zeroes.
I am supposed to use Schwartz reflection principle, but I don't see how. It tells me that $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is entire. It is clear that $|\overline{f(z)}|=1$ for all real $z$ but that does not allow me to use identity theorem yet. However, even if i could use identity theorem, I don't see how it would be helpful here. Any hints or solutions would be appricaated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, call $f^*(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ entire and satisfying same property as $f$; but now $g(z)=f(z)f^*(z)$ also satisfies $|g(x)|=1,  x \in \mathbb R$ but $g(x) \ge 0$ for $x$ real; so $g=1$ (first for $x$ real and then by identity), hence $f(z)f^*(z)=1$ for all $z$ so done!

Comment: Why is $g(x) \geq 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$? How do you know it always lands in the positive real numbers?

Comment: $f^*(x)=\bar f(x), x \in \mathbb R$ so $g(x)=|f(x)|^2 \ge 0$ (here of course $1$, but in general only $ \ge 0$) for real $x$

Comment: Thank you. I mistakenly thought $g$ was the composition of $f$ and $f^*$, not the product.

Comment: no problem - edited for clarity as I could see the possible confusion

Comment: @Conrad How did you even come up with that... Very nice solution.

Comment: than you for your kind words - $f^*$ is always a useful function to have when you have an entire $f$ since if $f \ne f^*$ (ie $f$ doesn't have real coefficients in the Taylor series at zero or any other real), $ff^*$ is actually positive on the real axis and "interesting" (in the case $f=f^*, ff^*=f^2$ so is not as interesting)